# Passing special character

Tags: php, html

I want to download a PDF file containing a special character `@`, but it's got an error. How do I pass a special character like `©` etc., I am using Object Orientated PHP.

Comment: 2 months, 19 questions, if any of the answers given to your questions solved your problem, please consider clicking on the big tick next to that answer. And please spellcheck your posts. At least.

Comment: This question attracted a guess answer, which turned out to be right, but the question itself needs more clarity. I will try to close it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download how?

You could use

```
file_get_contents('http://location.com/of.pdf');
```

?

You could save the contents then, or offer them for download yourself using the header() functions.